# Cannot get the cast syntax to work

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody help me in the below query , I am trying to convert the date from long date time format to shorter one but I cant put it together:

```
SELECT       dbo.bc_account.PublicID as PublicUniqueCodeID,

         dbo.bc_account.UpdateTime  select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103),
         dbo.bc_account.HiddenTAccountContainerID,

FROM         

        table 1 join table 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your query should be somewhat similar to this:

```
SELECT       
  PublicID as PublicUniqueCodeID,
  UpdateTime,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103),
  HiddenTAccountContainerID
FROM bc_account b
INNER JOIN another_table a ON b.fieldname = a.common_fieldname
```

See more information about [cast and convert on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: I wrote the query like how you nadvised and still it give the result as dattime (7 millisecond precision) .

Comment: I tried your solution but still the date type is the long format.(7 precision)

Comment: `select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)` gives `19/12/2015`. Isn't that what you want? If not, what kind of format would you like?